# What is the proper way to inform users that their device can't be supported for a weird reason?

Tags: mobile, iphone, standards

Apple has disregarded W3C standards by replacing the HTML5 video player with their own full-screen only video player in all iPhone browsers. Apple even went as far as to make it impossible to circumvent this behavior (with the exception of methods that would fry an iPhone CPU) by rendering video on HTML5 canvas as a work-around. Because of this, web applications which involve a user interface to be overlayed over the video player are broken on iPhone. There is no viable workaround. We explored all available routes. *This behavior is present on all iPhone browsers, not just mobile safari.*

So, because of this, I need to inform iPhone users that (even though our application has excellent mobile design and is developed to be highly performant on mobile devices) we cannot support iPhone with our web application. So I plan to handle this by displaying a page featuring an brief explanation. I can use graphics if that helps.

How can I explain this properly? (while):

- Not confusing the typical non tech-savvy user.
- Ensuring that the user understands this is not a failure on the part of our application development, but a failure on the part of Apple to support W3C specs (but the user doesn't necessarily understand what W3C standards are).
- Keeping the explanation brief.

Comment: Trying to understand your context a little more. What functionality are you trying to provide that must be performed on top of a video? Can you modify the workflow so iphone users can still perform a version of the action? You might get a lot of sad iphone users.

Comment: @nightning unfortunately, the functionality of the interface running over the video is so vital to the application, that it would be useless without the feature. Is that enough info? I'm trying to give as much info as is needed without exposing IP which isn't yet protected legally.

Comment: just say "This feature is not supported on iOS  (http://link.to.longer.explanation)" (the link here is a placeholder for your own link for explanation)

Comment: (maybe this is a dumb question) Would it be easier for you to create a standalone app instead of having a mobile web site ?

Comment: I'm confused... when did this happen? The dev guide still shows HTML5 support. Or are you talking about how Safari on iOS is designed so that every full screen video can only have the same video controls Apple designed for pause/play/etc.?  https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW13

Comment: Not looking from a UX PoV, but does this extend to ALL iPhone video, including those rendered in an application that doesn't use HTML video? Or could you maybe develop a native app using a proprietary player that doesn't use the iPhone default? I'm not sure whether this is possible, but it's what I'd consider.

Comment: Does this issue also exist in the iPhone Chrome app?  You could pop up a message saying "<appname> for iPhone requires the iPhone Chrome app".

Comment: could you replace the video by something else? (a static image, or an animation of some sort...) (You probably already considered those solutions and discarded them, but just in case)

Comment: I'd ask your marketing guys on how to phrase this. Such people are trained in turning any failure into a succes. ;-)

Comment: @nightning - I had a friend who ran into this problem while developing a website for adding custom subtitles to a video. Since that was the whole point of the app, it effectively became unusable on an iPhone.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - No, Apple requires that *every* web-browser on an iPhone use the built-in rendering engine, which is where the restriction in question is implemented.  Chrome and all the other browsers are effectively just skins/alternate UIs for the same functionality.  I don't know if that extends to apps which render HTML internally, but it definitely covers all the major browsers.

Comment: I remember someone whose error message if his drivers weren't compatible with a particular machine was 'Wrong computer purchased'.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: or in this case maybe more specific, "error detected in Cupertino".

Comment: @Max That would be a good idea, except one problem: We're able to develop apps nicely, with universal device support by using HTML5, JS, and CSS. We can even put apps on the App Store by using a web wrapper. But even then, Apple's anti-HTML5-video issue stops even a custom-built wrapper to render HTML5 video in-line. It's a native requirement to iPhone. So we'd have to literally start from square one and develop the app from scratch without HTML5 and CSS, costing us more to develop than the original app. This unfortunately isn't viable for a small start-up.

Comment: "we have excellent mobile design" - that doesn't work on 15% of phones :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I would keep the message short and simple,

**"Unfortunately, iPhone devices do not support W3C standard HTML video"**

This still allows you to shift the blame "devices don't support our application" as opposed to "we don't support your device".

## Why not longer?

1. If you go in to details about how Apple refuses to follow standards and how you guys have tried everything to fix it but can't it will make it sound like you are whining, disgruntled, and playing the blame game which comes off as unprofessional.
2. Users don't care. As soon as you say that a user can't use your application they have no reason to continue. They will not stick around to read reasons why they can't use it (that as you said, they won't understand anyway) they will simply move on.

## What can you do?

Other than simply telling the user that they can't use your application you can try to help mitigate your loss by directing them to an alternative. For example you can say "Still want to use our app? Click here to email yourself the link for later!" (if there is a desktop version) or point them to an iOS based version with less features if possible.

Comment: This sounds good to me. However small correction: iPads support the inline video so it isn't iOS, it's just iPhone.

Comment: @MediaWebDev Ah I see, very strange standards by Apple indeed. Quite a few design decisions they have made have put me in situations similar to this.

Comment: If there's a bug identifier, you could also encourage your users to request that feature from Apple, eg. «You can request your Apple representative to support the feature request 123<https://bugreport.apple.com/123> on iPhones»

Comment: I would maybe replace "our application" with "HTML5 video" or something similar. This makes it clear that it's not just your application, but *anything* that uses the standard. Without going into too much detail, it still gives enough information for the user that wants to do additional research. Otherwise, I can see a user interpreting the message as "we chose not to make our application work on iPhones", which obviously ins't the case.

Comment: `is not supported by` reads to the user like you are trying not to say `does not work with`, so you still take the blame

Comment: @DanHenderson +1 true, you can switch around phrases however you find necessary, the point I was making is just don't harp on it being someone else's fault, that doesn't bode well for you.

Comment: Why not flip the phrase and say `Unfortunately, iPhone devices do not support our application`? I think this more clearly puts blame on the iPhone. (anecdote: I told my wife the first phrase and asked her who was to blame, and she said "The makers of the app." I then told her my alternate phrase and asked her who was to blame, and she said "Apple.")

Comment: While this brief message is all that is required in app, it would be well complemented by a blog post on why.  This post would be picked up by people searching "<appname> iPhone" and provide information for the genuinely curious while not getting in the way of uninterested users.

Comment: @DanHenderson: And then add a second sentence to make absolutely obvious that this breakage is a deliberate decision by Apple: "iPad and iMac are not affected."

Comment: I agree it probably wouldn't hurt to add a "read more" button or something that leads to an extended description for those who really want to know. You just don't want to overload the main message for the majority who don't need to know more.

Comment: I proposed an edit suggestion combining my and @Cornstalks' suggestions, since both have received several upvotes.

Comment: Why so long? "Sorry, your device doesn't support HTML videos". By strapping away the Apple-W3C-School  blame the message gets shorter and also we don't use the word "W3C standard". I don't think that the users care will know (or want to know) what W3C standarts are - they're most likely interested in the video and in the video only

Comment: Why do we shift the blame? Why can't we just take the blame and be really sorry for what we just did. (No matter if we did it or not)

Comment: @JonasDralle true the message could be made shorter that way, but at that point removing two words likely won't make much difference. The idea is to just reduce cognitive load of all the details OP had, those two words only have minimal cognitive load. As for shifting the blame, the point is to not make users think you don't want to support their devices, if they think it is your choice to not support them they may not use your service in the future. Plus, if you accept the blame you'll likely get constant requests to fix something of which you have no control.

Answer (score 34):

If truly nothing can be done to make something work for iPhone users. Then be honest as possible in your notice saying the app is not supported, and succinctly provide the reason why, and how the user can get around it.

Here's a quote from an [article on medium](https://medium.com/@thomasfuchs/how-to-write-an-error-message-883718173322) about error messages that applies equally well for your use case.

> **Write an alert message that describes the alert situation clearly and succinctly.** An alert message such as “An error occurred” is mystifying to all users and is likely to annoy experienced users. (…) **Write informative text that elaborates on the consequences and suggests a solution or alternative.** Give as much information as necessary to explain why the user should care about the situation. (…) Informative text is best when it includes a suggestion for fixing the problem. (…) **Express everything in the user’s vocabulary.**

---

Example from Hulu:
[image]

Note: They don't provide a suggestion for fixing the problem because it's due to legal issues where there's nothing the user can do about it.

---

Possible wording for your message:

> ### Sorry, our app is currently not supported by iPhones
>
> Our application allows you to ______________ on your videos. This feature is currently not supported by iPhone browsers. To use the app, please use a computer, an iPad or an android device.

I would recommend emphasizing why your app is useful in order to encourage folks to take the extra step and try it on a different platform. It might give you slightly better results than a 100% drop-off wall for your target audience who uses iPhones.

Comment: technical note, iPad uses the same browser so will have the same issue.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I updated the wording based on the OP's comments on the other answer that it's only on iPhone. I actually have no idea.

Comment: Yes, based on that comment indicating that iPad does support the standard, it should definitely be included in the message, so that iPhone users know it's not some type of anti-Apple propaganda.

Comment: Downvoted because of a bad example. There is no technical problem between Hulu and foreign users.

Comment: @kinokijuf It still serves to show what a typical "not supported" message should look like and how much detail you should go into.

Comment: @DasBeasto The terms „worldwide”, „legal”, „streaming rights”, „international background” and „professional and personal interest” are likely to be dismissed as [buzzwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword) with no grounding in the technical reality

Comment: @kinokijuf While I agree with your comment, nonetheless, the route that Hulu took is a good example of how to present it in the OP's case layout-wise, provided they word it properly. As such, I think this is a good answer.

Comment: You might want to change computer to imac and android deice to non-apple device, to make it plainer that no other apple devices and no non-apple smartphones/tablets/computers are affected, and to avoid singling out android.

Comment: Including a long List of supported Devices will also probably shift the perception from "Lazy software not supporting IPhone" to "this runs on 100 devices and just IPhones cannot do it"

Answer (score 13):

If it makes sense in your case, you could use informal wording, like Trello does.

Also, while average user won't know what W3C or standards are, they usually have heard of HTML5 and/or it's video.

> Sadly, we're not allowed to make nice things with HTML5 video on iPhone
>
> It works fine on iPad or many other devices, though!

Comment: I'm not sure about the last message, it's not like people have two phones from both brands each.

Comment: @PierreArlaud: it comes across snarky, "consider getting an Android instead of an iPhone". Which is fine if you *want* to come across snarky, but a poor choice of words if you don't.

Comment: @PierreArlaud hmm, it sounded fair when I first worded it. I'll try to improve it.